# Firebase LogOut not working when doing it exactly like documentation

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

this is my code, every documentation I saw and every yt tutorial I found does the signout like this, but mine doesnt seem to work. I tried having a text view on my activity that changes depend on which user is logged in but it also isnt working

```
package com.example.tdlcolecciones


class LogInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
//lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient : GoogleSignInClient
lateinit var mAuth:FirebaseAuth
private val RC_SIGN_IN: Int = 123
var logout: Boolean = false
var email = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in)

    val log_in_btn: Button = findViewById(R.id.log_in_btn)
    val logOut: Button = findViewById(R.id.logOut)
    val logInText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.loginTextView)

    //logout = intent.extras?.get("logout")!! as Boolean

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    createRequest();

    val acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
    if (acct != null) {
        logInText.text = acct.email
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    }


    log_in_btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    })

    logOut.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        mAuth.signOut()
    })
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            val account: GoogleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            account.idToken?.let { firebaseAuthWithGoogle(it) }
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}

private fun createRequest() {
    // Configure Google Sign In
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("login_token")
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
     mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
}

private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this,
            OnCompleteListener<AuthResult?> { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    val user: FirebaseUser? = mAuth.getCurrentUser()
                    email = mAuth.currentUser?.email.toString()
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("email", email)
                    startActivity(intent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Auth Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })
}


}
```

I really cant find the problem, i have done this before but idk. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to implement Firebase sign-in with Google, I recommend you use [Google Identity One Tap](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d). If you want to use the old way, you can check [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) out.

Comment: Thanks! the first link helped out a lot